# Understanding valgrind output loss record

Tags: valgrind

When I run valgrind on my process and after process exit I get below output. What is the meaning of `"loss record 33,118 of 34,156"`

==4215== 2,048 bytes in 128 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 33,118 of 34,156

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the 33118th loss record of total 34156 records.

As described in [Memory leak detection](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.leaks) section of Valgrind documentation,

> ... it merges results for all blocks that have the same leak kind and sufficiently similar stack traces into a single "loss record".
>   ... The loss records are *not presented in any notable order*, so the loss record numbers aren't particularly meaningful. The loss record numbers can be used in the Valgrind gdbserver to list the addresses of the leaked blocks and/or give more details about how a block is still reachable.